# Concurrent Safety of time.Location

Tags: go

Is a `time.Location`, got from `time.LoadLocation("...")` safe to be accessed concurrently?

I ask this because I see that it does consider daylight saving time in it's calculations (Does it access a map loaded from the data zip file? Does it calculate it live? Do we need a lock for it? Or reloading is fast enough to do it every time?).

Comment: It's not a definitive answer, but as the `time.UTC` and `time.Local` locations are globally shared I would assume they are safe for use in multiple threads. There is also some discussion here of the Go maintainers mentioning caching as a possibility https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26106

Answer (score 0):

The only exposed method on `Location` is `String`. `Location` itself is defined with no exported fields:

```
type Location struct {
        // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
```

So once created, it should remain unmodifiable for the rest of its life. Hence it should be safe concurrent access.

As for `LoadLocation`, it does read from a file. So you can have a mutex protect every call to `LoadLocation`.

> The time zone database needed by LoadLocation may not be present on
>   all systems, especially non-Unix systems. LoadLocation looks in the
>   directory or uncompressed zip file named by the ZONEINFO environment
>   variable, if any, then looks in known installation locations on Unix
>   systems, and finally looks in $GOROOT/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip.

Comment: How can I be sure if `time.Location` is safe for concurrent use? It has not any public methods to modify it's state. But it reacts to daylight time automatically. Is this daylight time awareness concurrent-safe? Isn't something mutating back there?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get the "daylight time awareness" bit. A `time.Location` object once created should not change its value. Do you know of some method that can perhaps mutate this object?

Comment: If you use `t.In(location)` (for different `t` times spanned over a year) you'll see it considers daylight saving time; despite the fact it got created just once. How does it do that? It's obviously not a `pure` (side effect free) computation. Now; if so; is it concurrent-safe?

Comment: I did a quick test by creating two different objects of same location and passing in one of those to `t.In`. After this, `reflect.DeepEqual` on their values returns true. So I don't think the actual contents of `Location` object are changed even after the call to `In`. But having looked at some of the details I'll say it's probably not safe to assume concurrent access safety. So i'll be retracting my answer. Sorry about not being much help.

Comment: Actually I think participating in programming thinkering is always a great help for all of us, for this helps others to go on faster! Thanks!

Comment: Would you please update your answer based on your comment, so I mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody wants to avoid using `time.LoadLocation` and just wanted to convert `time.Time` to a timezone offset, you can use `time.FixedZone()` instead.

If we take a look at the code inside `time.FixedZone` (as of Go 1.20.5), you'll find that it actually caches the result:

```golang
// FixedZone returns a Location that always uses
// the given zone name and offset (seconds east of UTC).
func FixedZone(name string, offset int) *Location {
    // Most calls to FixedZone have an unnamed zone with an offset by the hour.
    // Optimize for that case by returning the same *Location for a given hour.
    const hoursBeforeUTC = 12
    const hoursAfterUTC = 14
    hour := offset / 60 / 60
    if name == "" && -hoursBeforeUTC <= hour && hour <= +hoursAfterUTC && hour*60*60 == offset {
        unnamedFixedZonesOnce.Do(func() {
            unnamedFixedZones = make([]*Location, hoursBeforeUTC+1+hoursAfterUTC)
            for hr := -hoursBeforeUTC; hr <= +hoursAfterUTC; hr++ {
                unnamedFixedZones[hr+hoursBeforeUTC] = fixedZone("", hr*60*60)
            }
        })
        return unnamedFixedZones[hour+hoursBeforeUTC]
    }
    return fixedZone(name, offset)
}
```